# How to transition between manufactured hardwood and vinyl rolled flooring?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, vinyl-flooring

We had the tan colored hardwood installed recently and the contractor put in these perpendicular pieces of wood wherever the floor butted up against another flooring type.  There used to be one of those brass nailed-in strips between these floors but he didn't replace that and just glued down the vinyl but as you can see it's coming back up.  Should I just get another brass transition strip or is there a better way?  You can see the other transition to the grey floor is pretty bulky but that's still way better than the current situation. We're not ready to replace the vinyl just yet.

[image: Flooring Transitions]Flooring Transitions

Answer (score 2):

If the vinyl isn’t going to be there for long, then yes — tack down a transition strip. Just put the nails on the vinyl side.